# Why is there a plastic sleeve on my HC-05 bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, components

I would like want to know why the bluetooth module has a plastic sleeve covering it?

Is it possible to remove it?

[image: HC-06]

Answer (score 4):

It is to protect it. You should keep it so that the modules lasts longer.

If you remove it, just don't do anything stupid.

Answer (score 3):

To protect it against ham fisted newbies from causing short circuits.

Yes, you can remove it, as long as you're not a ham fisted newbie that is going to cause short circuits.